# Iterate through a List<dynamic>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework request to retrieve many different informations, using several inner joins, so I use a dynamic List as a return type, but I can't seem to find a way to make it work when iterating through it.

I made a request with 4 tables but I'll take another example to simplify, say I have tables `Room` and `Kitchen`

```
var result = from r in Room
             join k in Kitchen on r.idKitchen=k.id
             where (r.id == myIDPassedAsParameter)
             select new { rId = r.id, kId = k.id}
             .ToList<dynamic>();
```

now when trying to access it I do the following :

```
foreach (var r in result)
{
    foreach (var item in r)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.rId + " " + item.kId);
    }

}
```

I keep getting a conversion exception on the second foreach. I couldn't find any way to fix this. I used it originally because my results returned are of anonymous type, so that's what I found to make the return possible.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, why are you converting it to a `dynamic` list? Second, the nested list implies the data is a list of lists which isn't true. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'd avoid using `dynamic` unless you really know what you're doing.  Can you at least use `object` instead?

Comment: I strongly suggest creating a type to handle the result. And I don't know why you have two foreachs. The result of your query should be something like this `var dynamicList = new List<dynamic>
            {
                new {rId = 1, kId = 1},
                new {rId = 2, kId = 2},
                new {rId = 3, kId = 3},
                new {rId = 4, kId = 4}
            };`

Comment: I'm no linq expert, but shouldn't this query return a list of anonymous objects that have rId and kId properties? If that's the case, why do you have the inner `foreach`?

Comment: Ok, I used it because of anonymous type problem, and I read that dynamic could resolve this problem but I guess I'm wrong. I tried with `List<object>` but it doesn't return the right type.

Comment: @DavidG I am trying to return a list that has anonymous types, but I don't really know how to do it, I stumbled upon `dynamic` and thought it would work, but I guess there is a better way of doing it I don't know of? (suggestions appreciated :) )

Comment: @DavidG Not sure I'm clear. The idea is I get many variables from many tables, so how to return them all at once?

Comment: Almost every time you need to resort to `dynamic` is an indication that you're trying to bodge something or that you're being lazy and not creating a concrete type to hold your data. Not always, but usually. You really should just create the types you need and return them.

Comment: @DavidG Hmm, you're probably right. Idk why I thought my repository has to stay clean from models and such but now that I think about it, it doesn't seem too bad ...

Comment: Models give you strict type checking, dynamic lets you do anything and get yourself into sticky situations, usually at runtime when it's too late!

Comment: @FlexabustBergson If you're using C# 7 you can also use `ValueTuple` to easily make new 'types'

Comment: @DavidG Yep! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @JakubDąbek I'll make sure to check it out thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I stated in the comment, I'd do this

```
private class RoomKitchenPair
    {
        public int RoomId { get; set; }

        public int KitchenId { get; set; }
    }

var result = (from r in Room
         join k in Kitchen on r.IdKitchen equals k.Id
         where (r.Id == myIDPassedAsParameter)
         select new RoomKitchenPair { RoomId= r.Id, KitchenId = k.Id})

foreach (var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.RoomId + " - " + r.KitchenId );
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'm gonna do this, seems way simpler and makes sense thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only going to iterate the results in a `foreach` loop, you don't need the `ToList` anyway, since the result itself is an `IEnumerable`.
Also, it's an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is your anonymous type - so you only need one `foreach` loop:

```
var result = from r in Room
             join k in Kitchen on r.idKitchen=k.id
             where (r.id == myIDPassedAsParameter)
             select new { rId = r.id, kId = k.id}

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.rId, item.kId);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do;

```
var result = (from r in Room
             join k in Kitchen on r.idKitchen=k.id
             where (r.id == myIDPassedAsParameter)
             select new { rId = r.id, kId = k.id})
             .ToList<dynamic>();

foreach (var r in result)
    {
          Console.WriteLine(r.rId + " " + r.kId);

    }
```

You already create dynamic object by

```
select new { rId = r.id, kId = k.id}
```

Comment: This throws an exception "object does not contain a definition for rId"

Comment: @Reedwanul That last sentence of yours is not true, that's not a dynamic type, it's an anonymous object. The two things are very different.